# blank json array in symfony2

Tags: web-services, symfony, json, symfony-2.3

i am writing webservice in symfony2 but i facing some problem regarding the output ,as it is giving blank output.

```
class DefaultController extends Controller {

/**
 *
 * @Route("/webservices/activity/{id}", name="user_json_activity")
 * @Method("get")
 */
public function activityAction($id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $list = $em->getRepository('FitugowebserviceBundle:activity')->findOneById($id);

    $r_array = $this->routes2Array($list);

    $r = array('activity' => $r_array);

    return new Response(json_encode($r));
}

private function routes2Array($routes) {

    $points_array = array();
    foreach ($routes as $route) {


        $r_array = array('activity' => $route->getActivity(),
            'icon' => $route->getIcon());



        $points_array[] = $r_array;
    }

    return $points_array;
}
```

}

When i try to fetch data for id=1  http://domain.org/fitugo/web/app_dev.php/webservices/activity/1 it is giving output as follows

{"activity":[]}

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Symfony. Double check your logic of building the array you return. Btw, you could use JsonResponse.

Answer (score 0):

It look very strange that you want get array with `findOneById` method. The first thing I suggest to add a check that the entity founded by id exist. Then look that `findOneById` returns and check your controller logic.